Is there a way of obtaining a copy of a thesis remotely?
Apologies if my question is a little vague. To hopefully clarify, I mean a thesis that has been digitized, can be downloaded by members of the holding institution, and is available on ProQuest. But, what if I am the other side of the world to the institution, have no institutional credentials of my own, and have no access to ProQuest?
And, tragically, I don't know anyone there either!

The usual approaches: Does your country have something like a catalogue of all holdings of the bigger libraries together? Have a look - you may be lucky. Then, is the author of the thesis still in academia? Drop an e-mail, perhaps you get a PDF copy. Less likely to work is asking the former supervisor of the PhD student by e-mail. Then, does ProQuest sell you an individual copy without a subscription? This may of course be too expensive for you. But perhaps you school provides support for such cases?

Ask one of their librarians.

Thanks to you both! It was a simple matter of emailing the library. Took  a discussion of less than five minutes. Madness. I must be so dense not to have considered that! Thanks very much!

Just curious - in what sense do you have "no access to ProQuest"? I was under the impression they would sell a thesis to anyone with a credit card. Obviously it'd be better to get it for free if you can (which in fact you did), but paying should still be an option if all else fails. Or did you simply mean that you don't have free access and can't afford to pay?

Nate—I learn something every day! I didn't realise they sell the theses they hold (I assumed that it it wasn't already freely available/OA, then it was restricted by copyright). I've checked, and in fact what I was after was indeed there. So yes, as it happens I have had a better result, as you say, but $40 wouldn't have broken the bank, I'm lucky enough to say, so it's something I will (hopefully!) remember next time I'm in the inevitable bind...

oatd.org will find links on major repositories; it's meant to provide access to thesis which are freely available.  For my thesis it finds both my institutional repository and the British Library's EThOS service (which is still down after a cyber attack).  Both allow downloading by anyone, in this case.  In general most UK theses end up on EThOS; other countries also have national repositories.
Google (regular or Scholar) is very patchy at indexing theses hosted by institutions, though it actually does find mine with my surname and a few uncommon keywords from the title.
Another tool is ndtld.org, but perhaps its most useful page is their index of national indices

Thanks Chris. Yes, EThOS is a major loss; I suspect it's at the bottom of the list for repair! But many thanks for those resources; OATD on its own seems a gold mine. It'll be very useful.
